# loop only provides the first output

Tags: r, loops, indexing

This is the data. So these are train stations:

```
   TwentyFourSeptTrainData

   $PTCAR_LG_NM_NL
   ALPHA
   BRAVO
   CHARLIE
   DELTA
   ECHO
   FOXTROT
   ALPHA
   BRAVO
   etc. etc.
```

So for every trainstation, I want to run the loop below, so that the value **c** becomes Station1 or Station2, depending on the row.

So I first must define b as every trainstation in that column, row by row.
And then I need to make sure that for every row in b, I get a corresponding c.

```
  for (b in TwentyFourSeptTrainData$PTCAR_LG_NM_NL) {

  if (b=='CHARLIE' | b=='ALPHA'){ 
  c = 'Station1'
  }  
  else if (b==BRAVO | b=='DELTA' | b=='ECHO' | b=='FOXTROT'){
  c = 'Station2'
  }      
  }
  print(c)
```

Because after that, I need to run a **function** on every row where I need every output of c.

But when I predefine b (before running the loop) as

b <- TwentyFourSeptTrainData$PTCAR_LG_NM_NL

After that, I print(c), but it gives me only one output; the first one. I think I'm doing something wrong with indexing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You keep replacing the value of `c` each time you go though the loop. I don't think you need a loop at all here, you are probably better off using the `ifelse` function. Maybe something like `ifelse(TwentyFourSeptTrainData$PTCAR_LG_NM_NL %in% c('CHARLIE','ALPHA'), "Station1", "Station2")`

Comment: and what if I would have 3 stations? So: Station1, Station2, Station3. Where ALPHA would be at Station3?

Comment: You could nest `ifelse()` statements or switch over to `case_when` from `dplyr`

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you initialize c as an empty list before your for loop? i.e.

```
c = c()
for (b in TwentyFourSeptTrainData$PTCAR_LG_NM_NL) {
    if (b=='CHARLIE' | b=='ALPHA'){ 
        c = c(c, 'Station1')
  }  
    else {
        c = c(c, 'Station2')
  }      
}
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to employ matrix manipulation in R instead of using loop:

```
#create data-frame
df <- data.frame(b = c("ALPHA", "BRAVO","CHARLIE", "DELTA", "FOXTROT", "ALPHA", "BRAVO" ))
df
  b
1   ALPHA
2   BRAVO
3 CHARLIE
4   DELTA
5 FOXTROT
6   ALPHA
7   BRAVO

#matrix manipulation
df$c[df$b == "CHARLIE" | df$b== "ALPHA"] <- "Station 1"
df$c[df$b == "BRAVO" | df$b == "DELTA" | df$b == "ECHO" | df$b == "FOXTROT"] <- "Station 2"
df
        b         c
1   ALPHA Station 1
2   BRAVO Station 2
3 CHARLIE Station 1
4   DELTA Station 2
5 FOXTROT Station 2
6   ALPHA Station 1
7   BRAVO Station 2
```